# how to use multiple folder into app.UseStaticFiles in .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, directory

I want to get access to multiple folder locations from my web api to display image.
I can't change the folder locations (depending on devices on which I don't have right to modify anything).

for one of the folders I did:

```
string FolderToListen = Configuration["xxx:yyy"];

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(FolderToListen),
});
```

and now I would like to do:

```
string FolderToListen2= Configuration["xxx2:yyy2"];
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(FolderToListen),
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(FolderToListen2),
});
```

but it doesn't work.
Is there any way to pass multiple folders to UseStaticFiles ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can register `UseStaticFolder` twice:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(FolderToListen),
});

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(FolderToListen2),
});
```

Comment: thanks, I should have tried that ... sometimes it is not necessary to look for difficult solution :)

Comment: what would be the relative request path for each folder if it is not provided?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CompositeFileProvider`:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new CompositeFileProvider(
        new PhysicalFileProvider(Folder1),
        new PhysicalFileProvider(Folder2)
    )
});
```